# What is the difference between the following three sort commands in unix?

Tags: unix, sorting

How are following sort commands in unix different?

```
1) sort -k1,4 < file
2) sort -k1,1 -k4,4 < file
3) sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 < file
```

Especially, #1 and #2 are confusing.
For example, the following example illustrates my points

```
$ cat tmp
1       2       3       t
4       2       4       c
5       4       6       c
7       3       20      r
12      3       5       i
2       45      7       a
11      23      53      b
23      43      53      q
11      6       3       c
0       4       3       z

$ diff <(sort -k1,4 tmp) <(sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 tmp)
1a2
> 1     2       3       t
5,6d5
< 1     2       3       t
< 23    43      53      q
7a7
> 23    43      53      q

$diff <(sort -k1,4 tmp) <(sort -k1,1 -k4,4 tmp)
1a2
> 1     2       3       t
5,6d5
< 1     2       3       t
< 23    43      53      q
7a7
> 23    43      53      q
```

And I did look at the sort's man page
In sort's man page, it says:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
 start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
```

But I don't understand this explanation. If it starts from POS1 and end it at POS2, then shouln't #1 and #3 commands above produce the same results?

Comment: Beautiful examples, well presented except for not using `diff -u`! I can't reproduce your result. I get identical output from command #1 and #3, using GNU sort and NetBSD's sort. What version of sort are you using? It might be a bug.

Comment: ++ for the explanation and interesting question

Comment: Followup to my own previous comment: I believe twalberg's answer is the most likely explanation for the difference between your sort and mine. Locales. Any sufficiently advanced locale-dependent behavior is indistinguishable from a bug.

Comment: It was due to the difference in `LC_ALL` as twalberg mentioned, and when I used `LC_ALL=C` there was no difference between #1 and #3. The version of my unix sort was `GNU coreutils 8.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that #1 treats the entire line as a single key, and sorts it lexicographically. The other two have multiple keys, and in particular, while #3 uses the same set of fields as #1, it does so in a very different way. It first sorts the list by the first column (whitespace belongs to the *following* field, and is significant, unless you specify `-b`), and *if two or more rows have an identical value in the first column*, then it uses the second key to sort that subset of rows. If two or more rows are identical in the first two columns, it uses the third key, etc.

In your first case, depending on your locale, you can get different results (try `LC_ALL=C sort -k1,4 < file` and compare it to, for example, `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -k1,4 < file`).

In your second and third case, since the keys are split on transitions from non-whitespace to whitespace. This means the 2nd and following columns have varying sized whitespace prefixes, which affect sorting order, since you don't specify `-b`.

Also, if you have a mix of spaces and tabs for lining up your columns, that could be messing with things.

I got your same results when I had `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` in my environment, but your expected results (i.e. no differences) using `LC_ALL=C` (SuSE Enterprise 11.2).

Comment: Unfortunately, the split doesn't discard the spaces. Each field includes the spaces that precede it, unless you add the `b` flag. `sort`'s behavior is far from intuitive (and locales make it worse)

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading that part... Made some changes to account for things I just learned myself...